# $F= \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i$ isn't necessarily connected where $F_{i+1} \subseteq F_i$ and $F_i \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ are closed and connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

In my attempt, I first show that $F$ is closed, this is since we can write $F= \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i = (\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i^C)^C$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i^C$ is a union of open sets, hence it is open, hence $F=(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i^C)^C$ must be closed.

From here, I am trying to construct an example. I was thinking of $F_i$ being two disjoint disks that are connected with a thick line between them, such that as $i$ grows the line becomes thinner and its thickness tends to zero. The problem is that in this case $F$ still has a one-point width line connecting the disks and this seems not good enough.

Will be happy for any help on this or a better example (Assuming the standart topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$)

Comment: For the counter-example, use the intersection of only two sets. That is easier to visualise and it does imply what you need.

Comment: corrected the title..

Comment: Ok, I see. I can tell you that it won't work if you are looking at a bounded region of space. The counter-example has to consist of unbounded sets. Perhaps you can find it then.

Comment: Thanks! so just to make sure I get the deal, we can also take the whole plane without $(0,1) \times (-i,i)$ right?

Comment: Exactly. That is valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And if we assumed $F_i$ are compact, then $F$ must be connected?

Comment: I think so... I haven't tried to prove it, but since you can choose a finite number of open sets covering your sets, that should suffice.

Comment: @Aladin: Yes, a countable intersection of nested continua is a continuum (nonempty compact connected [metric] space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider taking $F_i$ as the closed upper half-plane with $(0,1)\times [0,i)$ removed.

Answer (score 1):

Another example, $F_i$ us the union of the closed vertical rays starting at $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ and the closed half-plane above abscissa $i$.
$$  F_i = \{(0,y) : y \geq 0\} \cup \{(1,y) : y \geq 0\} \cup \{(x,y) : y \geq i\}  $$
As $i$ increases, the "bridge" between the two rays is yanked away.